# How can I Insert Conditions into an SQL SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to issue a query to my database via AJAX (to a PHP backend). I have 4 tables: Companies, Users, Invoices, Invoice_Lines. The important relationships are as follows:

```
Users.Company_ID -> Companies.ID
Invoices.Company_ID -> Companies.ID
Invoice_Lines.Invoice_ID -> Invoices.ID
```

I have written a simple parser in PHP that will break up the submitted SQL query into its components (columns, tables, and conditions).

I would like for the user to be able to write queries directly, but modify them before they are submitted to the SQL server so that all information is limited by the Company ID of the logged-in user. For example:

```
SELECT Users.ID, Users.Name, Users.Email
FROM Users
```

I would like the query to become:

```
SELECT Users.ID, Users.Name, Users.Email
FROM Users
WHERE Users.Company_ID = X
```

In a more complex example:

```
SELECT Invoice_Lines.Subtotal
FROM Invoice_Lines
WHERE Invoice_Lines.Invoice_ID = 4
```

Becomes

```
SELECT Invoice_Lines.Subtotal
FROM Invoice_Lines
INNER JOIN Invoices ON (Invoice_Lines.Invoice_ID = Invoice.ID)
INNER JOIN Company ON (Invoice.Company_ID = Company.ID)
WHERE Invoice_Lines.Invoice_ID = 4 AND Company.ID = X
```

It seems clear that I will have to create table aliases that do not conflict with the statement as it is already written. I'm not certain how to go about analyzing the query to decide what the most efficient way is to limit the input.

I intend to only support a subset of SQL (direct table columns with aliases, left and inner joins with tables and aliases and simple where expressions).

Comment: Rubber ducking here mostly?  Not sure I get the real question - seems you described the solution.  I've done similar projects many times and found having an OOP interface for the "SQL" can be useful.  [`Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) comes to mind.  Main benefit, you build the full SQL statement as far as 'from' and 'joins', then based off the actual columns used in the query it only joins on what it needs to.

Comment: I know the input and the output, but I'm having trouble on the analysis part. I can do it by hand for any query, but I can't envision the general algorithm that will convert it for me. I will probably end up adding a ton of INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I'd suggest looking at how Zend Framework goes about describing a SQL statement in an OP fashion with [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html).

1) Define your base SQL statement which includes all tables you be selecting columns from.

Lets say:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.table1Id = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.table2Id = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table4 on table4.table3Id = table3.id
```

2) You will allow users to select columns (and eventually I imagine constraints too) - *using arrays which could be swapped out for objects of course.*

```
$fields = array(
    'table1' => array(array('col1'/*actual field name*/ => 'col1_Alias' /*assigned alais*/), array('col2'=>'col2_Alias')
    'table2' => array(array('col1'=>'col1_Alias'), array('col2'=>'col2_Alias')
    etc...
);
```

Define that on the controller, use it for the options you give the user when they are building the query.  Then use it when they submit their selection to build out the SQL...

pseudo-ish code...

```
foreach ($selectColumns as $table => $col) {
     $cols[] = "{$table}.{$col['field']} AS {$col['alias']}";
}
```

In that loop you could track each table referenced and perhaps decide if it is needed in the SQL statement you will execute.  Would need to describe the nature of the JOINS to do that correctly though - again enter the OOP ability of something like Zend_Db_Select.

Not much meat here in my answer but hope it helps.